# Can not figure out why there is an overflow

Tags: css, overflow

All;

I guess I may misunderstand certain CSS attributes, but could anyone help me to explain why there is a scrollbar show up?

```
  <body ng-controller="main as main">
    <div class="app-container">
      <div class="chat-hist">
        <span>Why there is a scrollbar on the right?</span>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-input">
        <input class="chat-content" />
        <a href="#" class="chat-send">
          GO
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

and the style are:

```
<script>    
html, body {
        margin:0px; 
        padding:0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }


    .ng-cloak {
        display: none;
    }
    .app-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .chat-hist {
        width: 100%;
        flex:1;
    }
    .chat-input {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        flex: 0 0 30px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .chat-content {
        flex: 1;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left:10px;

    }
    .chat-send {    
        flex: 0 0 150px;
        font-size: 16px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        color: black;
        background-color: lightblue;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    .chat-send:hover {
        background-color: pink;
    }
    .chat-send:active {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }

</script>
```

I put the code pen here [No reason for scrollbar overflow](http://codepen.io/kuanslove/pen/XmmxYN)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   html, body {
        margin:0px; 
        padding:0px;
        width: 100%;
      overflow:hidden;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,could you tell me WHY there is a scrollbar?

Comment: Its to do with your  "flex: 0 0 30px". I'm not to sure why. Alternatively you can implement flex "flex: 0 0 0 30px" and increase the size of the last margin if needed. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, actually this is does not affect too much(I can just hide the overflow), the only thing I am concerning is to figure out why it behave like this. And I guess it is a browser issue, cos I tried this in FF38, no scrollbar shown up.